# mapping a function using 'pmap_dfr'

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to understand a piece of code from the book "Doing Meta-analysis using R"

`SuicidePrevention` is a data frame containg 9 rows and 10 columns (respectively `author`, `n.e`, `mean.e`, `sd.e`, `n.c`, `mean.c`, `sd.c`, `pubyear`, `age_group`, `control`)

Here's the code

```
SP_calc <- pmap_dfr(SuicidePrevention, 
                    function(mean.e, sd.e, n.e, mean.c,
                             sd.c, n.c, author, ...){
                      esc_mean_sd(grp1m = mean.e,
                                  grp1sd = sd.e,
                                  grp1n = n.e,
                                  grp2m = mean.c,
                                  grp2sd = sd.c,
                                  grp2n = n.c,
                                  study = author,
                                  es.type = "g") %>% 
                        as.data.frame()}) 


glimpse(SP_calc)
```

With this output:

```
Rows: 9
Columns: 9
$ study       <chr> "Berry et al.", "DeVries et al.", "Fleming et al.", "Hunt & Burke…
$ es          <dbl> -0.14279447, -0.60770928, -0.11117965, -0.12698011, -0.39247445, …
$ weight      <dbl> 46.09784, 34.77314, 14.97625, 32.18243, 24.52054, 54.50431, 29.99…
$ sample.size <dbl> 185, 146, 60, 129, 100, 220, 120, 80, 107
$ se          <dbl> 0.1472854, 0.1695813, 0.2584036, 0.1762749, 0.2019459, 0.1354517,…
$ var         <dbl> 0.02169299, 0.02875783, 0.06677240, 0.03107286, 0.04078214, 0.018…
$ ci.lo       <dbl> -0.4314686, -0.9400826, -0.6176413, -0.4724727, -0.7882811, -0.53…
$ ci.hi       <dbl> 0.145879624, -0.275335960, 0.395282029, 0.218512440, 0.003332195,…
$ measure     <chr> "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g"
```

I'm having a hard time understading the logic behind the code and didn't find the doceumentation on `pmap_dfr` very helpful. How does `pamp_dfr` itter through the rows of the dataframe? Does `function` extract its arguments from the column names?

I defined `my_function` as below and tried to pass one of the rows as its argument.

```
my_function <- function(mean.e, sd.e, n.e, mean.c,
                        sd.c, n.c, author,...){
  esc_mean_sd(grp1m = mean.e,
              grp1sd = sd.e,
              grp1n = n.e,
              grp2m = mean.c,
              grp2sd = sd.c,
              grp2n = n.c,
              study = author,
              es.type = "g") %>% 
    as.data.frame()}


my_function(SuicidePrevention[2,])
```

The output was this:

```
  study es weight sample.size se var ci.lo ci.hi measure
1    NA NA     NA          NA NA  NA    NA    NA       g
Warning message:
Either `totalsd` or both `grp1sd` and `grp2sd` must be specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the [purrr cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/purrr.pdf) has some pictures which are helpful for visualizing how the `map*` family of functions (including `pmap`) processes its arguments.

`map` iterates through each element of a list or vector passing them individually to a function. `map2` iterates independently through the elements of of 2 lists or vectors, passing elements with the same index to the function at the same time to collect a result. `pmap` expands this to an arbitrary number of lists or vectors.

A `data.frame` under the hood is a list of vectors, each element of the list is a column (try `as.list(iris)` to see this).

Consequently, `pmap` does not have sense of "rows" per se. It treats the `data.frame` as a list then maps the elements to the arguments of function. To more accurately simulate a single iteration of `pmap_dfr` you would need to call `my_function` more along the lines of this:

```
my_function(
  SuicidePrevention[2, "mean.e"], 
  SuicidePrevention[2, "sd.e"], 
  SuicidePrevention[2, "n.e"], 
  SuicidePrevention[2, "mean.c"],
  SuicidePrevention[2, "sd.c"], 
  SuicidePrevention[2, "n.c"], 
  SuicidePrevention[2, "author"]
)
```

Comment: I still don't understand how pmap applies a function to a row (an object in the list, as you said). How the arguments are passed into the `function`? Does `function` extract its arguments from the column names?
I changed the names of the arguments inside `function` in the code from the book, and it raised an error, which I'm guessing is because they no longer match the names of the columns.